# Swift 2 - sharedApplication() - Apple Music Search Api

Tags: ios, apple-music

I am trying to open from my app Apple Music app using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL` and search for an artist or having a link opening a related page where the song is.

Is there an api I can use to search on the Apple Music App? Is this possible?

```
let test = "https://itun.es/gb/RJEL2?i=915794180"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:test)!)
```

If I use that link the app opens up but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
let test = "https://itun.es/gb/RJEL2?i=915794180"
```

contains your search information you can get the contents of the url like such

```
let Session = NSURLSession.SharedSession()
var task = Session.dataTaskWithURL(test, completionHandler: {
   (data, response, error) -> Void in

   :
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: The `data` variable would contain the response of the server from your URL request as NSData. You can turn this into a string using `NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`.